# "Not Charging" Displayed When Charging iPad On Computer - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mac, usb, ipad

I've seen many people say that it is due to the USB port not giving off enough power, which I really don't think is true, as I have a Mac with two operating Systems (Mac OSX and Windows 7).

I just installed Windows 7 32 Bit and now all I am waiting for is Microsoft to actually reship me the product I actualy ordered which was Windows 7 64 Bit, but that won't be for some time.

So until then, is it a problem with some devise missing, or is it due to me using 32 bit?

I could not find any information relating to this, without having to relate with the USB ports.

Comment: What does the fact about having two operating systems have to do with the USB port power? The hardware supplies the power not the OS.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Realizing you are new, I am only commenting to help you improve your question because it is somewhat confusing to read. At some points you are discussing things which have nothing to do with the question being asked. Please take a minute to [edit] you post and remove irreverent details. There is more information in the [faq] and at [ask] to help you.

Comment: Thats the whole point @Brad Patton The hardware works, so I know it will work on Windows 7, but its not. It works just fine on OSX, but not on WIndows 7.

Comment: Ok Kyle you may want to reword your question to reflect because I didn't get that from reading it the first time.

Comment: iPad No Charge on Windows 7, iPad Charge on Mac OSX

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue.  This is the link to the [apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4060).  The new iPad's and iPad mini's will display "not charging" when attached to a standard USB port on most PCs.  Unless you have a high power USB port, which most people dont, you will see this.  It is misleading though, it actually is charging, just really slowly.  You are better off using the electrical outlet to charge the iPads.

Comment: Like I said Im using a Mac, so it is high powered.

Comment: I would check Device Manager in Windows, right click the appropriate USB hub, and choose Properties -> Power Management and make sure the option for limiting power to save battery is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

One of the key statements from the previously linked [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4060):

> When attached to a computer through a standard USB port (most PCs or earlier Mac computers) iPad will charge, but only when it's in sleep mode.